# Нужна ли запятая после «которые»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

Подскажите, нужна ли запятая после "которые"?

*Судьба подарит вам приятные знакомства, **которые** если и не сыграют яркой роли в личной жизни, то непременно помогут в делах.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После союзного слова [которые](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/90842) в этом предложении запятая не нужна.
Почему же? Потому что придаточное предложение с двойным союзом [если и не... то](http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=185) нельзя ни переставить, ни без потери смысла "убрать" из предложения.
*Судьба подарит вам приятные знакомства, которые **то** непременно помогут в делах.*

Из правил Розенталя:

> ...при «встрече» двух подчинительных союзов (или подчинительного союза и союзного слова) запятая между ними ставится, если изъятие второй придаточной части не требует перестройки главной части (практически — если дальше не следует вторая часть двойного союза ***то, так*** или ***но***, наличие которой требует такой перестройки), и **не ставится**, если дальше следует указанная вторая часть двойного союза.

Четыре романа, **которые если и не** потрясут мир, **то** уж по крайней мере заставят его выделить и отгородить для меня местечко. [Евгений Прошкин. Механика вечности (2001)]

Может быть, я, перебирая маршрут, упомянула о мостах, по которым мы ехали, а может быть, повода не было вовсе, но отец Глеб, внезапно ставший совершенно серьезным, заговорил о странности, **которая если и не** бросается в глаза, **то**, во всяком случае, открывается внимательному наблюдателю. [Елена Чижова. Лавра // «Звезда», 2002]

[Запятая на стыке двух союзов](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140)

Comment: Простите за поправку, но у Вас точка в цитатах стоит до имени автора, а должна после. Розенталь, "Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация", § 57: "Если указание на автора или на источник цитаты следует непосредственно за текстом, то оно заключается в скобки, причем точка ставится после закрывающей скобки (а не после цитаты): «Значение Белинского в истории русской общественной мысли огромно» (Луначарский).

Comment: Дело в том, что это не моё личное оформление, а предложения, взятые из Нацкорпуса русского языка. (https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%B5) Здесь нет ни кавычек, ни курсива, если их нет в авторском предложении. Возможно, именно поэтому  авторство указывается в квадратных скобках — как дополнительная информация. Менять что-то при использовании НКРЯ я не имею права.

Comment: В нацкорпусе -- это всё техническая разметка. На мой взгляд, нет оснований её соблюдать. Это всё равно что при цитировании копировать точь-в-точь вёрстку книги-источника, включая шрифт. Если уж соблюдаете досконально разметку Нацкорпуса, то придётся делать также шрифт, каким набраны источники, меньше и бледнее.

Answer (score 2):

Не нужна. В составном союзе *если... то...* запятая перед *если* не ставится.

Примеры:

- Которые если и приносили с собой бутылку водки, то и спасибо...
  (Войнович);
- ― Правильно, ― мрачно согласился старший из великанов, и по его
  глазам было видно, что сам он из тех, которые если что и выбрасывают
  из своей жизни, то уж никак не хитрость (Искандер).

Правила [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_185) и [здесь](http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=1191).

Comment: Кстати, по поводу цитирования. Ваше первое предложение процитировано неверно. Правильно так: *Которые если и приносили с собой бутылку водки, то и спасибо...* И по поводу утверждения "В составном союзе *если... то...* запятая перед *если* не ставится". Оно тоже неверно, так как перед "если" может находиться обособленная конструкция (деепричастный оборот, или причастный, или вводное слово). В этом случае запятая, конечно же, ставится. *Впрочем, **если и не** губками, **то** грек все равно торговал* (А. Т. Аверченко).

Comment: *По умолчанию* не ставится. В случае деепричастного оборота (или др.) запятая ставится, строго говоря, не перед "если", а после деепричастного оборота (или др.) (потому что она аргументируется не наличием "если", а именно причастным оборотом (или другим), который она закрывает.
Про многоточие в цитате — спасибо, исправил.